# Using old F1 visa due to Administrative Processing

Tags: usa, student-visa, passport, study, refusal

I recently applied at the American Embassy, New Delhi, for a new F1 visa for my PhD program. After the interview, my passport was collected by the embassy and my case was put under Administrative Processing - 221(g).

Now I don't know if I will get my visa in time for my classes. However, I still have an F1 visa valid until 2018 from my previous program (different university, same SEVIS), so I was wondering if I could just withdraw my application, get my passport back and fly on that visa. Would this create any problems for me in the future? Or maybe has the embassy canceled my old visa when I submitted it?

Comment: What degree was that if you can include? Did you already graduate from that program? Have you considered applying for OPT?

Answer (score 1):

You can request a temporary withdrawal of your passport for the purpose of study, your 221g application will be put on hold. It is up to the embassy whether they allow your visa to be valid or cancel the already valid visa. Also, if you are able to travel back to the US, it is uncertain by what time you need to return so that your 221g processing can resume.

Please share your experience and what you eventually ended up doing. I am in a similar situation as yours.

Thanks!